# Is it possible to make games in Python without Pygame?

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to design a games in python without using an pygame ??? If it is then tell us about an little bit for an start-up..or else if there is any other platform to design a python game gave a little bit start up about it...

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) directly, but maybe it's a little rough to start.
Other option I know it's [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) which has a lot of tools, mostly modelling and rendering but you can also make games and its scripting is in python.

But I think outside Pygame and Blender, there's not too much options...

Answer (score 0):

A popular one that is supposedly easier to grasp and learn is [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home). It takes out a lot of the fine tuning that pygame delivers, the best parts, but that's nothing to be concerned with if you're looking for an easier starting position to launch your programming needs.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame is only one of many python libraries which provide access to a graphics API. To create a game using python, here are some other options:

- Panda3D - a game engine with python as the main language
- Ogre's python component
- Kivy
- DirectPython11 - microsoft's Direct3D11
- PyOpenGL/Pyglet
- Blender's game engine (only available before 2.80)